# Trying to access Login element but there is no element id or class

Tags: java, jsoup, httpurlconnection, getelementbyid

Hi new to programming couldnt find a question like this. Im trying to create an autologin script for a free finance site so i can scrape some stuff off. Im trying to access this site
http://www.quantumonline.com/login.cfm . And then get access to the username and password box so i can login with my info via java, and then scrape some useful information.
However i dont see any elementids by which to access the username and password boxes.

My code is based off this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example but instead of using HtpsURLConnection i am using HttpURLConnection as this website doesn't use Https.
When i use Chrome to inspect the elements i get.

```
<input type="text" name="acctname" size="15">  //username element
<input type="password" name="pswrd" size="15">  //password element
```

//How do i get to the elements if there is no elementid? Below is the code that errors out from the website. I used the input name field
 as the elementid but thats obviously not correct

```
public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    // For id
    Element loginform = doc.getElementById("acctname");

    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("pswrd"); <<errors here with NULL pointer exception, because there is no tag pswrd.
```

Comment: You can use the `name` attribute.

Comment: how do i implement that. I mean the Elements class in jsoup doesnt have getElementsbyName. Hope im making sense.  Thanks -Niko Balanis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `[attr=value]` selector with the name attribute (see [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)).

For example with your sample code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element acctname = doc.select("input[name=acctname]").first();
Element pswrd = doc.select("input[name=pswrd]").first();

System.out.println(acctname);
System.out.println(pswrd);
```

Will output:

```
<input type="text" name="acctname" size="15" />
<input type="password" name="pswrd" size="15" />
```

Comment: thanks for the help while that worked great. In the end tho i used the HtmlUnit class as it made things easier.

Comment: Ya I tried before but I guess I don't have enuff rep to do that yet . Hitting the upvote tells me I need minimum 15 rep for me to be able to upvote. When I get some I deff will :).